# Not-equal to character in R

Tags: r

What is the command for printin the string that are not equal to a specific character? From the data below I would like to print the number of rows where the t5-column does not start with `d-`. (In this example that is all the rows)

I tried

dim(df[df$t5 !="d-",])

df:

```
             name freq            mir start end mism  add   t5  t3       s5       s3    DB ambiguity
6     seq_10002_x17   17 hsa-miR-10a-5p    23  44  5GT    0  d-T   0 TATATACC TGTGTAAG miRNA         1
19    seq_100091_x3    3 hsa-miR-142-3p    54  74    0 u-CA d-TG   0 AGGGTGTA TGGATGAG miRNA         1
20    seq_100092_x1    1 hsa-miR-142-3p    54  74    0 u-CT d-TG   0 AGGGTGTA TGGATGAG miRNA         1
23    seq_100108_x5    5 hsa-miR-10a-5p    23  44  4NC    0  d-T   0 TATATACC TGTGTAAG miRNA         1
26 seq_100113_x1219 1219    hsa-miR-577    15  36    0    0  u-G   0 AGAGTAGA CCTGATGA miRNA         1
28    seq_100121_x1    1 hsa-miR-192-5p    25  45  1CT u-CT  d-C d-A GGCTCTGA AGCCAGTG miRNA         1
```

Comment: Try `sum(!grepl("^d-", df$t5)]`. What you want is not to check that the strings are not equal to `"d-`". None of them is. What you want to check is that the string does not start with `"d-`". `grep` and `grepl` can be used to check whether certain patterns appear in a string. Look at `?grep` for more information.

Comment: Yes, i did, sorry! The final ] should be a ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one row in your data that has a t5 entry that does not start with "d-". To find this row, you could try:

```
df[!grepl("^(d-)",df$t5),]
#               name freq         mir start end mism add  t5 t3       s5       s3    DB ambiguity
#26 seq_100113_x1219 1219 hsa-miR-577    15  36    0   0 u-G  0 AGAGTAGA CCTGATGA miRNA         1
```

If you only want to know the row number, you can get it with `rownames()`

```
> rownames(df[!grepl("^(d-)",df$t5),])
#[1] "26"
```

or with `which()`,

```
> which(!grepl("^(d-)",df$t5))
#[1] 5
```

depending on whether you want the row number counting from the top of your data frame or the row number according to the value on the left.

Comment: The OP actually wants to print the number of rows.

Comment: Sorry to be bothersome... He wants the count of rows, not the row number. So it should be `nrow(df[!grepl("^(d-)",df$t5),])` or `sum(!grepl("^(d-)",df1$t5))`. And what is `df1`?

Comment: @Stibu I had another script running where df was already used in another context. Thanks for pointing this out. It should be `df`; I will edit. If the count of rows is requested, your answer in the comment is correct and I don't wish to repeat it. I think that the OP's statement "print the number of rows" leaves some room for interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

```
df1 <- df[!grepl("^d-",df[,8]),]
nrow(df1)
print(df1)
```

Comment: Depending on how exactly the data look, your solution might  not be entirely correct. The OP asks for rows where `t5` does not *start* with `"d-"`, while your solution catches all the rows where `t5` does not contain `"d-"` anywhere. Of course, from the small sample one might expect that things like "ad-TG" do not exist, but I think it would be a good idea to use `"^d-"` as the pattern.

Comment: Yes I agree fully. :)